# Use javascript to compare php variable from DB with form field onchange and show/hide span accordingly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Restated:

There is a php variable:
    $address

There is a form variable
    addy

There is a span on the page that I want to display if the value the user enters into the form variable does not match the php variable

For example, the $address variable = "123 4th St"

The User types in the addy form field "132 4th St"

Once the user clicks out of the field (a text input), because the addresses do not match, I want span id add_ck to display, "Addresses do not match"

But if the user changes the contents of addy back to "123 4th St", span id add_ck will not display anything, or "".

I know you can do a show/hide thing with an onchange event, and I have used that before with dropdowns. But comparing text entry 'change' (determined by clicking outside of the field, or into some other field) to a php variable to trigger a span display/no-display event is what I am trying to find out.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<? 
$address = "123 4th St";
?>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var db_address = '<?php echo $address; ?>';
document.getElementById('address_field').addEventListener("change", function(){
compare_addresses();
});
var compare_addresses = function(){
var new_address = document.getElementById('address_field').value;
var the_span = document.getElementById('add_ck');
if(db_address == new_address)
{
//The addresses are equal. Show 'add_ck'.
add_ck.style.display = 'block';
}
else
{
//The addresses are not equal. Hide'add_ck'.
add_ck.style.display = 'none';
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form" method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" name="addy" id="address_field">
<input type="submit"> 
</form>
<span id="add_ck">Testing</span>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: ___unclear what you're asking___

Comment: You want mix javascript with php. Not possible this way.

Comment: It can be a little tricky figuring out what goes where in your logic but you're kind of blending these languages in a way they're not quite meant to be mixed. You need to either let JavaScript completely handle the input and logic or split it up in a way that the PHP state can be continually accessed. PHP is primarily going to be looking for form submission (you can use it for event handling but JS/JQ simply do a way better job of that). If you can't fire the PHP from the "action" then everything needs to be done in JS. A PHP action does not necessarily need to reload the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your input field should have an id. Let's say we call it `address_field`:

```
<input type="text" name="addy" id="address_field">
```

Put the value from PHP in a JS variable:

```
var db_address = '<?php echo $address; ?>';
```

Add an event listener to your textbox:

```
document.getElementById('address_field').addEventListener("change", function(){
   compare_addresses();
});
```

In the `compare_addresses` function you compare the two strings:

```
var compare_addresses = function(){
    var new_address = document.getElementById('address_field').value;
    var the_span = document.getElementById('add_ck');
    if(db_address == new_address)
    {
        //The addresses are equal. Show 'add_ck'.
        the_span.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
        //The addresses are not equal. Hide'add_ck'.
        the_span.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi edvinHolm - see above revised code. When I click into the addy field and change the address to something other than the $address variable, there is no change in the span. It stays visible no matter what.

Comment: You have to run the JavaScript after creating the elements, in other words, place the `<script>` tag underneath your form.

Comment: I suppose upvoting and checking the selected answer is another way to say "+1" or "thanks" :)

Answer (score 0):

The PHP is server-side and javascript is on client-side so the var *addy* seams to be undefined here. The *addy* var should be defined only if the form was submitted in the var $_POST['addy']